# Grouping and Summing Up To 30 Columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, grouping, field-names

I have a cross tab query displaying the final results to be presented in a Report format.

I need about 30 columns to be grouped and summed together as one master column.

Having issues with Microsoft 2010 and also with the tables and field names.

Comment: _Having issues with Microsoft 2010_ What is Microsoft 2010???

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do it:

```
select (sum(t1.col1) + sum(t1.col2) + sum(t2.col3) + ...) as master
from yourTable1 t1, yourTable2 t2, ...
where ...
```

Comment: What about any preceding code string if one of the names isn't from the original table but from a crosstab querry?

Comment: Do you just mean the columns are spread over multiple tables?

Comment: Yes they are coming from multiple tables.